# Pygame clock not accurate

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a Five Nights at Freddy's "fan game", but the clock part is not working. I have function called 'time', set to run once per frame. It counts the frame the program is on and when it equals 40 (I have it running at 40 fps), it adds 1 to the variable 'seconds' and when seconds equals a certain amount, the hour will change. There are 3 problems:

When the camera is up (move the mouse to the bottom of the screen), the new time image is blitted over the old one, but as soon as you put the cameras back down (just move the mouse the the bottom of the screen again) it goes back to normal.

The time is not accurate. Like I mentioned earlier, I have it so the hour will change every 10 seconds. The problem is that when I time it, the time between hours is not consistent (i.e. it will take 15 seconds to change to 1:00, then 18 seconds to change to 2:00, then 17 seconds to change to 3:00, and so on.)

The last problem is that the 6:00 image never gets blitted. Instead of the 6:00 image replacing the 5:00 image, the program simply blitts no images to show the hour after 5:00.

My code is as follows:

```
import pygame, random
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), pygame.FULLSCREEN, 32)
pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

twelve = pygame.image.load('images/12.png')
one = pygame.image.load('images/1.png')
two = pygame.image.load('images/2.png')
three = pygame.image.load('images/3.png')
four = pygame.image.load('images/4.png')
five = pygame.image.load('images/5.png')
six = pygame.image.load('images/5.png')

office_pic = pygame.image.load('images/office.png')
stage = pygame.image.load('images/stage.jpg')
building_map = pygame.image.load('images/map.png')
building_map.convert_alpha()

breathing = pygame.mixer.Sound('sounds/breathing.wav')

screen_width = 1280
screen_height = 800

x = 0
x_move = 0

camera_up = False
v = 0
camera = stage

fps_tick = 0
seconds = 0
hour = 1


def time():
    global fps_tick, seconds, hour
    fps_tick += 1

    if fps_tick == 40:
        seconds += 1
        fps_tick = 0

    if seconds == 10:
        hour += 1
        seconds = 0


    #blit the hour
    if hour == 1:
        screen.blit(twelve, ((screen_width-150), 30))
    elif hour == 2:
        screen.blit(one, ((screen_width-150), 30))
    elif hour == 3:
        screen.blit(two, ((screen_width-150), 30))
    elif hour == 4:
        screen.blit(three, ((screen_width-150), 30))
    elif hour == 5:
        screen.blit(four, ((screen_width-150), 30))
    elif hour == 6:
        screen.blit(five, ((screen_width-150), 30))
    elif hour == 7:
        screen.blit(six, ((screen_width-150), 30))



def office(mouse_x, click):
    global x, x_move

    if camera_up == False:
        if mouse_x >= (screen_width/2) + 200 and mouse_x <= (screen_width/2) + 400:
            x_move = 6
        elif mouse_x <= (screen_width/2) - 200 and mouse_x >= (screen_width/2) - 400:
            x_move = -6
        elif mouse_x > (screen_width/2) + 400:
            x_move = 12
        elif mouse_x < (screen_width/2) - 400:
            x_move = -12
        else:
            x_move = 0

    x -= x_move

    if camera_up == False:
        screen.blit(office_pic, (x,0))



def cameras(mouse_x, mouse_y, click):

    global camera_up, v

    if mouse_y >= (screen_height - (screen_height / 6)) and camera_up == False and v == 0:
        camera_up = True
    if not mouse_y >= (screen_height - (screen_height / 6)) and camera_up == True:
        v = 1
    if mouse_y >= (screen_height - (screen_height / 6)) and camera_up == True and v == 1:
        screen.fill((0,0,0))
        camera_up = False
    if not mouse_y >= (screen_height - (screen_height / 6)) and camera_up == False:
        v = 0

    if camera_up == True:
        screen.blit(camera, (0,0))
        screen.blit(building_map, (screen_width-650, screen_height-426))




def main():

    global x, x_move, camera_up, v, click

    while True:       

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
               if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                   pygame.quit()
                   quit()

        mouse_xy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        mouse_x = mouse_xy[0]
        mouse_y = mouse_xy[1]
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()


        office(mouse_x, click)            

        cameras(mouse_x, mouse_y, click)

        time()


        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(40)



main()
```

Comment: two things: 1) the image name for 6 is incorrect, 2) using frame rate that way is not accurate - there will be background process running and at some point the engine is going to do some garbage collection - instead you should use the real-time clock to push time - it just need to be scaled

Comment: Counting frames isn't a guaranteed way to measure time; 40fps is the ideal rate of the engine but it doesn't reliably produce frames at that rate. It will vary based on the amount of work being done per frame. Use real time: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks

Comment: Little tip regarding you're coding style - read this, it's great! [Google Python Style Guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do something every 10 seconds, better use pygame's event system and simply schedule an user event with `pygame.time.set_timer`.

For example,

```
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 10000)
```

will trigger the `pygame.USEREVENT` event every 10 seconds. You listen for it like for every event in your main loop:

```
...
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
       if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
        hour += 1
...
```

If you look closely, you see why the image does not change between `five` and `six`: you use the same image.

```
...
five = pygame.image.load('images/5.png')
six = pygame.image.load('images/5.png')
...
```